# JavaScript Map - setting nested properties

Tags: javascript

I have this Map

```
let map = new Map(Object.entries({
   a: 1,
   b: {
        c: 2,
        method() {console.log('test')}
      }
   }
));
```

Now, I want to change map.b.method.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: Get the value of key "b" and update the "method" property?

Comment: Have you tried, `map.get('b').method = ...`?

Comment: Thanks, but is it not possible with map.set()?

Comment: @UnknownJoe `map.set('b', { ...map.get('b'), method() { … } })`

Comment: A `Map` is, and I'm being really broad here, basically just an `Object` that allows you to use things other than `Strings` as keys.  How would you do this with a regular `Object`?  Start there and tell us what issues you run into.

Answer (score 6):

It's just an object stored inside the map. [Get a reference to it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) and modify it as you'd like.

```js
let map = new Map(Object.entries({
  a: 1,
  b: {
    c: 2,
    method() {
      console.log('test')
    }
  }
}));

map.set('b', {
  ...map.get('b'),
  method: function() {
    console.log('It works ;)');
  }
});

map.get('b').method();
```